# Hidding a part of widget?

Tags: javascript

I have widget for selling tickets. When the content of widget is shown/loaded on page, I need to hide the bottom (third) part of widget. I think it is div with class "new-page-footer-wrapper". How can I do that?

The code of widget is:

```
<!-- Ticket Tailor Widget. Paste this in to your website where you want the widget to appear. Do no change the code or the widget may not work properly. -->

<div class="tt-widget">
<div class="tt-widget-fallback">
    <p><a href="https://www.tickettailor.com/all-tickets/18209/4848/ref/website_widget/" target="_blank">Click here to buy tickets</a><br />
        <small><a href="http://www.tickettailor.com?rf=wdg" class="tt-widget-powered">Sell tickets online with Ticket Tailor</a></small>
    </p>
</div>

<script src="https://dc161a0a89fedd6639c9-03787a0970cd749432e2a6d3b34c55df.ssl.cf3.rackcdn.com/tt-widget.js" data-url="https://www.tickettailor.com/all-tickets/18209/4848/ref/website_widget/" data-type="inline" data-inline-minimal="false" data-inline-show-logo="true"  data-inline-bg-fill="true">
</script>
</div>
<!-- End of Ticket Tailor Widget -->
```

Comment: Provide more info like any libs which you with the project

Comment: I think this question could be answered more easily if you add a little more information about this statement:  'I think it is div with class "new-page-footer-wrapper".' This part of your question is a little vague.

Comment: Also - my first thought would be to update the markup a little bit so that the part of the widget you want to hide (the bottom third) is it's own div. In that case you can use a CSS class "i.e. hide" that has the rule "display: none" to hide it initially. Is the markup something you have access to changing?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a set height and then use `overflow: hidden`

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p> This can be seen </p>
  <p> This can also be seen </p>
  <p> This cannot be seen </p>
</div>
```